# Arrastrar y soltar en tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Quiero escribir una rutina aparentemente sencilla con tkinter: tengo dos Label con diferentes textos separados entre sí en la misma ventana. Lo que necesito es arrastrar el texto de una de las etiquetas hacia la otra; al soltar, los textos de las etiquetas deben intercambiarse.

¿Es posible? ¿Alguien me puede mostrar un código que lo haga?

Comment: No hay nada que venga con Tkinter que haga eso mismo. Tendrás que hacerlo vos mismo. Podrías intentar resolverlo por tu cuenta y luego, si te trabas con algo más concreto, editar esta pregunta y mostrar lo que lograste hasta ahora. Así, demostrarás que eres parte de esfuerzo por responder tu propia duda, no parecerá que quieres que te hagan la tarea y la comunidad recibirá mejor tu pregunta.

Comment: Por cierto, voy a agregar la etiqueta Python. Siempre que hagas una pregunta sobre Tkinter, también incluye la etiqueta Python y, si es necesario, la versión de Python en la que esperas la solución. Así, tu pregunta llegará a más gente. Por favor lee las recomendaciones de uso de la etiqueta aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info